Almalinux 9 same bash script works differently from shell and from cron
Running same bash script gives different output running from shell or as a cron job.
Description

Create simplest text file with content

touch /tmp/forbashtest ; printf "Lorem ipsum we have Release 1.1.5 version and also should be \$dbstore variable in text so let's check\n" > /tmp/forbashtest 

Create simple bash (i.e. text_ask.sh) to check if a text exists inside this file

#!/bin/bash
version=$(/usr/bin/ack "Release 1.1.5" /tmp/forbashtest | wc -l) ; printf "version count = $version\n" ;
dbexist=$(/usr/bin/ack "dbstore" /tmp/forbashtest | wc -l) ; printf "dbexist count = $dbexist\n" ;
if [[ "$version" -eq "0" ]] && [[ "$dbexist" -eq "0" ]] ; then
echo "Version CHANGED and DB insert not exists";
else
echo "Version still 1.1.5 and DB INSERT at place";
fi
exit ;
sh 

First run from shell
sh /a/test_ask.sh > /tmp/test_ask_shell.txt ;

Output /tmp/test_ask_shell.txt - TRUE answer as should be
version count = 1
dbexist count = 1
Version still 1.1.5 and DB INSERT at place

Second run as cronjob adding to /var/spool/cron/root the following line
15 6 * * * sh /a/test_ask.sh > /tmp/test_ask_cron.txt ;

Output /tmp/test_ask_cron.txt - FALSE answer !
version count = 0
dbexist count = 0
Version CHANGED and DB insert not exists

The question is - HOW IT COULD HAPPEN ? I do not see any logic.
chown 0755 /a/test_ask.sh did not help, set absolute path /usr/bin/ack instead of just "ack" - same.
"AS IF" crond service using /var/spool/cron/root has not enough of the root privileges to perform commands in BASH script or something like that.
Alma9 is CentOS based - but I never met such a problem with CentOS - any scripts running under CROND service (or LOGROTATE service) were performing SAME like directly run from root shell.
Would be very obliged for the ideas to understand and try to fix,

sh (Bourne-shell) is usally not bash (Bourne-again shell).

tried cron like bash /a/test_ask.sh > /tmp/test_ask_cron.txt ;  - same result

I installed ack and ran your setup + raw ack calls in the script.  The raw ack calls generate no output (hence the 0 counts) when run by cron.
Running a web search on ack AND cron I found this github issue link. OP has the same issue, ie, ack not working with cron.
Towards the bottom of that link user hoelzro provides the following explanation:

If ack detects that standard input isn't a tty, it assumes it's a pipe
or file redirect and tries to filter that instead.

So, when run under cron ack senses no tty and thus switches to looking for input from a pipe or file redirect, and since no such input exists (in this case) the input is effectively 'empty' and no output is generated which in turn means wc -l returns 0.
The solution/workaround: add --nofilter to the ack call, eg:
/usr/bin/ack --nofilter "dbstore" /tmp/forbashtest

From ack --help:
  --[no]filter                  Force ack to treat standard input as a pipe
                                (--filter) or tty (--nofilter)

After adding --nofilter to all of the ack calls my crontab job now generates the expected results:
version count = 1
dbexist count = 1
Version still 1.1.5 and DB INSERT at place

NOTE: I'm just passing along what I found in my brief searching; I have nothing to do with the design or development of ack so cannot speak to why it behaves this way

Thank you, incredible! I thought of anything but such specific use of ACK. You saved my day, may be not one.
